# I'm trying to change the button hover color to transparent but isn't working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover

Here is the code below. I'm trying to change the button hover color to transparent. the div class = "button_container" while the button class = "btn"
I changed the color initially but it isn't working and I would appreciate any help that can be thrown my way.
Thank you in advance

I know this is mostly code I'm posting but I can't figure it out. I believe the knowledgeable community here on Stack overflow can help me figure it out. Cheers

```
.button_container {
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 30%;
}

.description, .link {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.description {
    font-size: 35px;
}

.btn {
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: space-around;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 48px;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
    display: flex;
    text-align: -webkit-left;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#70AECD 0%,#022350 100%);
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3.99rem;
    margin: -10px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}

.btn span {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
}
.btn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2.25rem;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    padding:119px;
}
.btn:before {
    content: url(https://.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: -11.25rem;
    width: 0rem;
    height: 73%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 858%;
  width:347%;
  background: #ffae25;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(37deg);
  transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(47deg);
}

.btn:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(47deg);
  transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}

.link {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.link a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change your opacity so you can make it as transparent. I am not sure if this is what you mean or you want the text to change the color?? If so i change it. I dont have your html so this is what I came up with Let me know.

```css
.button_container {
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 30%;
}

.description, .link {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.description {
    font-size: 35px;
}

.btn {
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: space-around;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 48px;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
    display: flex;
    text-align: -webkit-left;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#70AECD 0%,#022350 100%);
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3.99rem;
    margin: -10px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}

.btn span {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
}
.btn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2.25rem;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    padding:119px;
}
.btn:before {
    content: url(https://.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: -11.25rem;
    width: 0rem;
    height: 73%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 858%;
  width:347%;
  background: #ffae25;
  opacity:.3;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(37deg);
  transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(47deg);
}

.btn:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(47deg);
  transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  z-index:1;

}

.link {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.btn > a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="button_cotainer">
    <div class="btn"><a href="#">button1</a></div>
    <div class="btn"><a href="#">button2</a></div>
    <div class="btn"><a href="#">button3</a></div>
    <div class="btn"><a href="#">button4</a></div>
<div>
```